# Can't build with roslaunch as a dependency

Tags: ros, roslaunch, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been given a repo with roslaunch as a dependency in the CMake files, and it fails to build like so:

```
-- Could NOT find roslaunch (missing: roslaunch_DIR)
-- Could not find the required component 'roslaunch'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "roslaunch" with
  any of the following names:

roslaunchConfig.cmake
roslaunch-config.cmake
```

So I tried creating a fresh catkin package to see if I can recreate the issue. Even with the fresh catkin package roslaunch is causing `catkin_make` issues, I'll walk through them here.

Just to confirm at the beginning, `roslaunch` is installed. The first time I saw the build error below I installed it with `sudo apt install python3-roslaunch`. If that method of install is the problem that'd be an easy fix, but I think it's okay.

```
eric@laptop:~/tutorials/catkin_ws$ roslaunch -h
Usage: roslaunch [options] [package] <filename> [arg_name:=value...]
       roslaunch [options] <filename> [<filename>...] [arg_name:=value...]

If <filename> is a single dash ('-'), launch XML is read from standard input.
...
```

Okay, how to create the issue. I started from the basic [ROS build-a-package tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage) like so:

```
eric@laptop:~/tutorials$ source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
eric@laptop:~/tutorials$ printenv | grep ROS
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/noetic/share
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/noetic/etc/ros
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros
ROS_DISTRO=noetic
eric@laptop:~/tutorials$ mkdir -p catkin_ws/src/
eric@laptop:~/tutorials$ cd catkin_ws/
eric@laptop:~/tutorials/catkin_ws$ ls
src
eric@laptop:~/tutorials/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws
...
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/build"
eric@laptop:~/tutorials/catkin_ws$ ls
build  devel  src
eric@laptop:~/tutorials/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash
eric@laptop:~/tutorials/catkin_ws$ cd src/

eric@laptop:~/tutorials/catkin_ws/src$ catkin_create_pkg figuring_out_roslaunch_issue roscpp rospy roslaunch std_msgs
Created file figuring_out_roslaunch_issue/package.xml
Created file figuring_out_roslaunch_issue/CMakeLists.txt
Created folder figuring_out_roslaunch_issue/include/figuring_out_roslaunch_issue
Created folder figuring_out_roslaunch_issue/src
Successfully created files in /home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/src/figuring_out_roslaunch_issue. Please adjust the values in package.xml.

eric@laptop:~/tutorials/catkin_ws/src$ cd ..
eric@laptop:~/tutorials/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/noetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/noetic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.8.10", minimum required is "3") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Forcing gtest/gmock from source, though one was otherwise available.
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.8.10") 
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests3
-- catkin 0.8.10
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - figuring_out_roslaunch_issue
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'figuring_out_roslaunch_issue'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(figuring_out_roslaunch_issue)
-- Could NOT find roslaunch (missing: roslaunch_DIR)
-- Could not find the required component 'roslaunch'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "roslaunch" with
  any of the following names:

    roslaunchConfig.cmake
    roslaunch-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "roslaunch" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "roslaunch_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "roslaunch" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  figuring_out_roslaunch_issue/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Very simple to recreate, very odd. I won't go through the full gamut of printouts, but roslaunch appears to have been installed in `/usr/share/roslaunch`, which those files mentioned in `/usr/share/roslaunch/cmake`:

```
eric@laptop:~/tutorials/catkin_ws$ ls /usr/share/roslaunch/cmake/
roslaunchConfig.cmake  roslaunchConfig-version.cmake  roslaunch-extras.cmake
```

I tried adding those paths to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and `roslaunch_DIR` as environment variables, but they all got the same build error. I tried the following combos:

```
eric@laptop:~/tutorials/catkin_ws$ echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
/usr/share/roslaunch:/home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/devel:/opt/ros/noetic
eric@laptop:~/tutorials/catkin_ws$ echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
/usr/share/roslaunch/cmake:/home/eric/tutorials/catkin_ws/devel:/opt/ros/noetic
eric@laptop:~/tutorials/catkin_ws$ echo $roslaunch_DIR
/usr/share/roslaunch/cmake
eric@laptop:~/tutorials/catkin_ws$ echo $roslaunch_DIR
/usr/share/roslaunch
```

This is running ROS noetic on 20.04. I'd love hearing any suggestions people have!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383609/can%27t-build-with-roslaunch-as-a-dependency/) by [Eric Schneider](https://answers.ros.org/users/4619/eric-schneider/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2021-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Just to confirm at the beginning, `roslaunch` is installed. The first time I saw the build error below I installed it with `sudo apt install python3-roslaunch`. If that method of install is the problem that'd be an easy fix, but I think it's okay.

No, it's not okay, and this could be the cause of your problems.

`python3-roslaunch` is not the correct package, but an [UpstreamPackage](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages). The correct package would be `ros-$ROS_DISTRO-roslaunch`. In your case: `ros-noetic-roslaunch`.

You cannot (and should not) mix these two package sources.

See the linked wiki page for more information, and see [“upstream packages” increasingly becoming a problem](https://discourse.ros.org/t/upstream-packages-increasingly-becoming-a-problem/10902/) on ROS Discourse for a meta-discussion about them.

PS: I am surprised though how you could have a ROS Noetic installation *without* `roslaunch`, as it's a very low-level dependency.

Seeing as you've already installed (s)one upstream package(s): could you tell us how you've installed ROS? Perhaps you have only a partial install.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-01**:
And PPS: `roslaunch` is a Python package. I'm not sure I've ever seen it as a `build_depend` (well, that's not true, before it could be used as a `test_depend` it was listed as a `build_depend`).

**Comment by [Eric Schneider](https://answers.ros.org/users/4619/eric-schneider/) on 2021-08-01**:
Love it, super simple fix, thanks! `sudo apt remove python3-roslaunch` and `sudo apt install ros-noetic-roslaunch` did indeed fix the problem.

I don't know why roslaunch wasn't already installed, I followed the [vanilla ROS install](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu) instructions a few weeks ago and installed `ros-noetic-desktop-full`. My best guess is that I accidentally screwed up the version that is originally installed.

The reason I installed `python3-roslaunch` is that I was prompted to like so. Maybe I had forgotten to source noetic, saw this, ran it, and messed with the underlying version that way?

```
eric@laptop:~$ roslaunch
Command 'roslaunch' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install python3-roslaunch
```

**Comment by [Eric Schneider](https://answers.ros.org/users/4619/eric-schneider/) on 2021-08-01**:
As far as I can tell `roslaunch` is not a `build_depend`, it's just called with `find_package` in CMake. I've inherited a repo recently that [is trying out this ROS package on github](https://github.com/ChielBruin/ros_faster_rcnn/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt). `roslaunch` appears in the CMake file but not `package.xml`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-01**:
Anything in a `find_package(..)` is by definition a `build_depend`.

The fact it isn't actually listed as a `build_depend` (or a `test_depend`) is actually "even worse".